# Is there any way to imitate the dragging event on JavaScript for CSS?

Tags: css, responsive-design, menu

I've been researching for a way to imitate the dragging event on CSS. But I found nothing. What I want to do is to create a mobile menu that is like the Gmail app menu, which I can see by dragging it. Anything in mind? 
Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by imitating? Do you want to use Javascript for it?

Comment: @Gh05d no. The less JavaScript, the better.

Comment: The answer is no - Javascript is for your interaction, CSS is your layout. So no, any dragging, tapping or moving about of stuff as a response to user input will go through JS (apart from :hover or :active, but those will not work here)

Comment: @somethinghere oh, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can! There is an example: https://codepen.io/100ants/pen/zYOPNrV

```html
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
<div class="menu">
    Menu!
    <div class="handle"></div>
</div>
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
textarea {
    height: 15px;
    resize: vertical;
    width: calc(50% + 9px);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-height: 118px;
    cursor: unset;
    min-height: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.menu {
    background: #37474f;
    padding: 50px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: -131px;
    position: relative;
    .handle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        background: #ffca28;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 5px solid #fff;
    }
}
```